# Double recursion to find smallest multiple using only certain digits

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

This is the problem statement my question stems from (from Hackerrank): *You are given an integer N. Can you find the least positive integer X made up of only 9's and 0's, such that, X is a multiple of N? X is made up of one or more occurences of 9 and zero or more occurences of 0.*

I thought I would use double recursion but I'm having trouble understanding how to make it work. My function takes in "multiple", which is a string (so that I can append either '0' or '9' to it in further function calls and not have to deal with arithmetic), and "divisor".

Basically I wanted to keep calling my function, adding either 9 or 0 to "multiple" at every call, returning the final "multiple" when it's finally divisible by "divisor". I was envisioning it as a tree of function calls splitting every time between function(multiple + '9', divisor) and function(multiple + '0', divisor).

However, it seems once I call return, it doesn't get to the second function call:

```
#multiple is a string
def rec_nine_zero(multiple, divisor):
    if int(multiple) % divisor == 0:
        return multiple
    else:
        return rec_nine_zero(multiple + '9', divisor)
        return rec_nine_zero(multiple + '0', divisor)
```

The below works:

```
print(rec_nine_zero('9', 1111))
```

However, if I try this (where the desired multiple is 90):

```
print(rec_nine_zero('9', 5)
```

It crashes and tells me basically that the stack blew up, meaning it never got to the second function call.

One problem I can see is that even if I manage to get the return statement to call both functions (with multiple + '9' and multiple + '0'), I feel like all of the branches of the function call tree except one (the one that finally finds the right result) will keep going until the stack says "annnnd...we're done".

**EDIT**: Based on Prune's answer, here is my new function:

```
def rec_nine_zero(multiples, divisor):
    for multiple in multiples:
        if int(multiple) % divisor == 0:
            return multiple
    new_multiples = []
    for multiple in multiples:
        new_multiples.append(multiple + '0')
        new_multiples.append(multiple + '9')
    return rec_nine_zero(new_multiples, divisor)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It blows up because you've done this in the canonical fashion of depth-first search.  The first branch you try in a string of 9's, as long as needed to find a solution.  Since there isn't any such solution for N=5, you recur until you blow the stack.

Change over to breadth-first.  Generate and test your smallest string, '9'.  When that fails, recur on the list of strings you want to extend: ["9"].

In the recursion, you append '0' and '9' to each candidate in the list.  On the first recursion, this gives you ["90", "99"].  With N=5, you'll return success on this stage.  If you have some other number, such as 7, you'll recur with this new list.

On the next step, you'll test the list ["900", "909", "990", "999"], and continue this process until you succeed.

BTW, you can perhaps make this easier if you quit converting between string and int: just start with 9.  The next stage will work on 10*x and 10*x+9 for each x in the previous list.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: i think I actually understood what you wrote (new feeling for me) about DFS and BFS. I rewrote the function and included it as an edit in my original question, would you mind please taking a look? Also, are you saying that doing the arithmetic with powers of ten is faster than going from string to int every time? I did the int() thing on purpose to avoid the arithmetic but it could've easily been miguided on my part.

Comment: You got it!  Of course, you *should* already know this from your own testing.  If you have doubts, give it some multi-digit prime numbers to grind on.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for confirming. I remember struggling a lot with all those concepts when I started studying CS; it seemed at the time I would never be able to wrap my head around them, but I'm glad I stuck with it (and did a lot of math...), a lot of those ideas are starting to really make sense.

Comment: For fun I'm going to see if i can implement DFS with a depth limit, as in if it reaches a certain digit length it comes back to a higher branch level and goes from there; that could be good practice even if not the best way to solve this particular problem.

Comment: We've all been there.  I remember my girlfriend teaching me the proper implementation and use of recursion back in ancient times (yes, a female ace programmer in the late 1970s).  Doing this with a depth limit is also an interesting exercise.  Pass the depth as a parameter; avoid global variables.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm on it :) I always upvote every answer out of principle (because it's always an effort on the answerer's part) unless it's really completely wrong and rushed with zero thought put into it.

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer but heres another simpler way to do the question -

```
def rec_nine_zero(divisor):
    d = divisor
    while True:
        if all([True if i in '09' else False for i in `d`]): return d 
        else: d+=divisor

print rec_nine_zero(111)
```

Anyways to answer your question -

There are some caveats in your code which might give you some tips about recursion.

- First you have a return statement under another return statement in the same construct and because of this the second return statement is never run.
- Second thing is you are missing a **base case** for recursion which is needed to stop the recursion from going on. What your code is doing right now is just appending 9 and 9 and 9 ...., your 1st case works because luckily, 111 has a multiple of 999. In other cases it fails miserably.

And unfortunately, you cannot construct a base case for this problem if you solve it this way. The solution that @Prune gave is the right one.

Hope it helps!

Yeah you got it right! Anyways, I like shortening the code so here you go with the canonical bfs-

```
def rec_nine_zero(multiples, divisor):
    que = [];que.append('9')
    while(len(que) != 0):
        k = que.pop()
        if int(k)%divisor == 0:return k
        que.append(k+'9');que.append(k+'0')
    return -1   

print rec_nine_zero('9', 5)
```

PS - I'm sure it can be shortened more!

Comment: Thank you for the advice and also the alternative solution; it's amazing it can be done so easily, it didn't even come to my mind. Would you mind (if you haven't seen it yet) taking a look at my EDIT at the end? I added a version of the function (I think) Prune was talking about, basically doing BFS instead of DFS.

Comment: Yes, this is simpler, certainly more straightforward ... but it can be very slow for numbers that don't hit a solution quickly.  The recursive solution is *less* susceptible to the same problem.  I do recommend changing the **else** line to simply **d += divisor**.

Comment: Also, the proper use of **in** plus **all** is nicely Pythonic.